# Can I use std::unique_lock to AttachCurrentThread and DetachCurrentThread from JNI?

Tags: android, c++

```
    class SmartAttachCurrentThread
    {
    public:
        SmartAttachCurrentThread(JavaVM *jvm, JNIEnv *env) : jvm(jvm), env(env)
        {
            //TODO: throw if jvm null?
            jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        }

        ~SmartAttachCurrentThread()
        {
            jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
        }

    private:
        JNIEnv *env;
        JavaVM *jvm;
    };
```

I'm trying to design a smart class that attaches the current jni thread for me and detaches automatically, so I can use like this:

```
    {
        JNIEnv *env;
        SmartAttachCurrentThread smartAttachCurrentThread(jvm, env);
        jclass clazz;
        clazz = env->FindClass("com/app/myapp/");
        //call class method
        //thread is detached here prevnting memory leak 
    }
```

However, the `AttachCurrentThread` inside `SmartAttachCurrentThread` will not change the `JNIEnv *env;` on the line

```
 {
        JNIEnv *env;
```

What would be a good solution for this? Do I really need this class or can I use `std::unique_lock<T>` for some type `T` that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class constructor is taking the `JNIEnv*` parameter *by value*, that is why the `env` variable outside of the class is not being updated.  You need to pass it *by reference* instead, eg:

```cpp
class SmartAttachCurrentThread
{
public:
    SmartAttachCurrentThread(JavaVM *jvm, JNIEnv* &env) : jvm(jvm)
    {
        if (!jvm)
            throw ...; // whatever you want

        if (jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) != JNI_OK)
            throw ...; // whatever you want
    }

    ~SmartAttachCurrentThread()
    {
        jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    }

private:
    JavaVM *jvm;
};

...

{
    JNIEnv *env;
    SmartAttachCurrentThread smartAttachCurrentThread(jvm, env);
    // now you can use env as needed...
}
```

Or, pass it *by pointer*, eg:

```cpp
class SmartAttachCurrentThread
{
public:
    SmartAttachCurrentThread(JavaVM *jvm, JNIEnv **env) : jvm(jvm)
    {
        if (!jvm || !env)
            throw ...; // whatever you want

        if (jvm->AttachCurrentThread(env, NULL) != JNI_OK)
            throw ...; // whatever you want
    }

    ~SmartAttachCurrentThread()
    {
        jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    }

private:
    JavaVM *jvm;
};

...

{
    JNIEnv *env;
    SmartAttachCurrentThread smartAttachCurrentThread(jvm, &env);
    // now you can use env as needed...
}
```